# Git Push Heroku Master results in Fatal Error When Trying to Deploy App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been trying to push my first simple app to heroku for deployment. However, after ensuring the right gem files are installed (PG for Postgres), and having the proper login credentials on heroku and installing heroku on my Mac, it gives me the following message each time I attempt to upload it. How can I solve this issue so I can upload my code.

```
My-MacBook-Air:jrv JRV$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: ------k@gmail.com    
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Authentication successful.
My-MacBook-Air:jrv JRV$ git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When i try the --verbose command i get the following:

```
Joses-MacBook-Air:jrv JRV$ git push heroku master --verbose
Pushing to git@heroku.com:tranquil-beyond-7774.git
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When i try Heroku Keys and Keys:Add, I got the following response again

```
my-MacBook-Air:jrv JRV$ heroku keys
=== kwikteck@gmail.com Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...+Q2oPy1mCf kwikteck@gmail.com@github.com
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...PTa++gCorp kwikteck@gmail.com@github.com

my-MacBook-Air:jrv JRV$ heroku keys:add
Found existing public key: /Users/JRV/.ssh/github_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /Users/JRV/.ssh/github_rsa.pub... done
my-MacBook-Air:jrv JRV$ git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
my-MacBook-Air:jrv JRV$
```

I am currently running Rails 4.0.0, ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0], with heroku-toolbelt/3.2.3 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3

Comment: It looks like you don’t have your SSH keys set up correctly. Have a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: I looked at the link, and tried to use the solutions below, but I am wondering what regenerating another SSH code would do.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you're not sending the right public key to Heroku to verify your identity.
You can try running `git push heroku master` with the `--verbose` option and see which publickey is really sent.

Comment: what i am getting is as follows:   
    Joses-MacBook-Air:jrv JRV$ git push heroku master --verbose
    Pushing to git@heroku.com:tranquil-beyond-7774.git
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Hm, okay, not as verbose as I hoped it to be. Can you try a ```heroku keys```?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
heroku keys:add
```

in your app directory

Comment: Use comments instead unless you got the full solution

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer using the suggestions here and I did the following:

1) Went to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys
2) After using the heroku     keys:add command to ensure the keys were uploaded and 
3) getting no result, I deleted the keys in place using $ ssh-add -D
4) I created a new key using $ ssh-keygen -t rya ; it will ask for a password for the key for security 
5) Added the keys back to Heroku using $ heroku keys:add
6) It will ask which key set you wish to you use, I choose the new key made by my system 
7) After it accepted I checked using $ heroku keys 
8) Then I was able to $ git push heroku master --verbose

System accepted the upload